# Deploying OSGi Servlet to Domino

Tags: osgi, xpages, domino-designer-eclipse

I have written a servlet using the directions in this tutorial: http://www.slideshare.net/fiorep/domino-osgi-development slides 34 to 57.  This worked well and was easy to debug when deployed via the pde.launch.ini.  Now I want to work out how to deploy it to another server.

From what I can figure out, I think the preferred way is to create an OSGi bundle and deploy it via an updatesite.nsf.  When I try to add a new local update site to the update site, it prompts me for a site.xml.  This is where it falls apart for me - where does that file come from?  Have I missed some steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want go to update site way, you first need to create a feature project, add the required plugins to this project. 
Afterwards you need to create an Update site and the Feature project.
Finally click on build or build All.
Then there you have you have your update site somewhere on your local machine.
Point to the site.xml of this update site project when you want to import it in a update site Database.

Answer (score 1):

For your OSGi project you have to create another project of type "Updatesite project". Add your OSGi project and all dependencies to that project and build it. This project will generate/contain the site.xml you need to deploy on Domino via the updatesite.nsf.

https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_create_an_update_site_(site.xml)%3F