# how to use XPages: A ClientSide State by Sven Hasselbach in Domino Designer

Tags: osgi, xpages, domino-designer-eclipse

Could you someone please help me how to use XPages: A ClientSide State by Sven Hasselbach in Domino Designer.

The code provided on the GIT does not have site.xml to install in the domino Designer.

http://hasselba.ch/blog/?p=2115

Answer (score 4):

You have to create your own OSGi Developement environment first, then you can create a new Plugin project and import the following files / folder:

- `/src`
- `/META-INF`
- `build.properties`, `plugin.xml`

Now you can change the secret keys in

`/src/ch/hasselba/xpagesclientstate/application/ClientStateManagerImpl.java`

Next you have to create a Feature project, and an Update Site project and click on `Build`.

Then you have a `site.xml`which can be imported into Designer & Domino server.

Comment: The link shared from you did not resolve my issue with the access restriction in the Domino Designer. Could you please help me in same. I really would like to use your pulgin in my application.

Could you please help

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an update site project.  Details are here:

https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_create_an_update_site_(site.xml)%3F

For reference, see the answers to this question [Deploying OSGi Servlet to Domino](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32904840/deploying-osgi-servlet-to-domino)